# Probability of dice being rolled a $7$ eight times in $10$ rolls

Tags: probability, dice, binomial-distribution

A pair of dice is rolled, and the player watches for sevens. What is the probability that it takes exactly $10$ rolls to observe $8$ sevens? 
 My approach is that I know the dice are rolled until $8$ sevens occur. I know the probability of rolling a $7$ is $\frac{1}{6}$.
 I want to know how to find the probablity of obtaining $7$ sevens in the first $9$ rolls followed by a seven on the tenth roll? This is what I need to do to answer the question.

Comment: It needs to be a seven at the tenth roll, so you have 7 events to distribute over 9. How many ways can that be done?

Comment: would that be $7^{9}$

Comment: the first of the seven can be any of the nine positions, the second can be in any of the eight left and so on...

Comment: so am I doing order with replacement formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** On each roll (of the two dice), you can either have a success (a seven) or a failure (anything else). Additionally, the order of the successes doesn't matter, as long as you get eight out of ten.

Do you know any distribution that would be suited for this?

**Answer:**
The answer is to use the binomial distribution, which gives the probability of $k$ successes out of $n$ trials, when the probability of a success is $p$, given by
$$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$
In your case the probability of a succes is $p=\frac{1}{6}$, the number of trials is $10$ and the number of successes for which we want to calculate the probability is $k=8.$ Insert these values into the formula and get the desired result.

*Edit:* As *mathreadler* correctly points out, the problem formulation actually asks for the probability of getting $k=7$ successes in $n=9$ trials *and then* getting a seven on the tenth trial. With these values of $n$ and $k$, the probability is then 
$$\binom{n}{k}p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

Comment: I have the requirements for discrete random variables like $f(x)>0$ where $x\in t$ and the sum of $x\in t$ where $f(x)=1$

Comment: I really have not used random variable and distributions for questions

Comment: @behold That is all correct. Should I change the hint into a complete solution, or do you want to read up on it and have a go at it yourself first? For example, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Specification

Comment: hint me please. I been looking at this for 30 minutes

Comment: @behold I updated my answer.

Comment: the 10 is $n$?@Lovsovs

Comment: I never seen this setup. I do not have your equation in my notes but I see what is going on

Comment: @behold Yes, $n=10$ for your problem. The binomial distribution is one of the first discrete distributions that you learn, because it is so widely applicable. Read a bit about it, I promise you will find it useful for many problems! :)

Comment: I am getting a $5.953741808E^{-7}$ for $(\frac{1}{6})^{8}$. I cant get an answer with that. Is it something else I need to do

Comment: When I plug in my numbers, I am getting $(\frac{1}{6})^{8}$ $(\frac{5}{6})^{2}$  I got the other part done

Comment: nevermind, I got $0.000744419829$ as my probability

Comment: @behold You're missing the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{10}{8}=45$. Multiplying that on also you get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binom(10,8)(1%2F6)%5E8*(5%2F6)%5E2).

Comment: @Lovsovs: Actually it will be $\binom{9}{7}$ since we know the tenth must be "hit" or we would have hit all 8 before tenth which was not allowed.

Comment: @mathreadler Thank you, I've edited my answer accordingly!

Comment: @mathreadler thanks, I adjusted and got $0.00001488435452$ as the probability

Comment: oops by changing the exponent to $k+1$ I got the correct answer. Thanks again